# Equivalent statements about solvable groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is Dummit & Foote $\S$3.4 #8:

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Prove that the following are equivalent:
>
> (i) $G$ is solvable
>
> (ii) $G$ has a chain of subgroups: $1=H_0\trianglelefteq H_1 \trianglelefteq H_2\trianglelefteq\dots\trianglelefteq H_s = G$ such that $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is cyclic, $0\le i \le s-1$.
>
> (iii) all composition factors of $G$ are of prime order
>
> (iv) $G$ has a chain of subgroups: $1=N_0\trianglelefteq N_1 \trianglelefteq N_2 \trianglelefteq \dots \trianglelefteq N_t = G$ such that each $N_i$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $N_{i+1}/N$ is abelian, $0\le i\le t-1$
>
> [For (iv), prove that a minimal nontrivial normal subgroup $M$ of $G$ is necessarily abelian, and then use induction. To see that $M$ is abelian, let $N\trianglelefteq M$ be of prime index (by (iii)) and show that $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy\in N$ for all $x,y\in M$. Apply the same argument to $gNg^{-1}$ to show that $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ lies in the intersection of all G-conjugates of $N$ and use the minimality of $M$ to conclude that $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=1$.]

I have proved (i)$\Rightarrow$(iii)$\Rightarrow$(ii)$\Rightarrow$(i), and now I am trying to use the book's hint to prove that (iii)$\Rightarrow$(iv), but I'm confused as to why they even suggest taking $N\trianglelefteq M$. In my understanding, $M$ being a minimal normal subgroup indicates that there are no proper nontrivial subgroups contained in $M$. By an earlier exercise, I know that there is a composition series of $G$ which includes $M$, and since it is minimal it would have to take the following form:
$$1\trianglelefteq M \trianglelefteq G_2 \trianglelefteq \dots\trianglelefteq G_r=G$$
Then we can use our hypothesis from (iii) to conclude that $M$ must have prime order, so $M$ is cyclic and therefore abelian. Given that $M$ is minimal, why do they even suggest considering some normal subgroup $N\trianglelefteq M$?

I don't think I'm really understanding the composition series concept correctly - for instance, in the book it mentions that the composition factors in a composition series are unique, that is if we have $1=N_0\le N_1 \le \dots \le N_r = G$ and $1=M_0 \le M_1 \le \dots \le M_s = G$ then $r=s$ and the composition factors are isomorphic (up to permutation), but I don't even agree with the $r=s$ part. Based on what I understand, $1\trianglelefteq \langle s\rangle\trianglelefteq \langle s,r^2\rangle\trianglelefteq D_8$ and $1\trianglelefteq\langle s\rangle\trianglelefteq \langle s\rangle \trianglelefteq \langle s, r^2 \rangle \trianglelefteq D_8$ are both valid composition series. This is really trivial, and to avoid it all that is required is to define composition series with *proper* normal subgroups, but that's not how it's defined in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following claim in your question is wrong: "In my understanding, M  being a minimal normal subgroup indicates that there are no proper nontrivial subgroups contained in M".

It must be: M being a minimal normal subgroup means there are no proper non-trivial **normal** subgroups (of the big group!) contained in M"

So what F&D are saying makes sense: there still can be some proper non-trivial subgroup N normal in M *but not in G*: $\,1<N\triangleleft M\,\,,\,\,N\rlap{\;/}\triangleleft G\,$

Comment: Ah - that does make sense. I knew the normal part (forgot to type it in my question above), but forgot that it was in reference to the group as a whole ($G$). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is meant by *proper* normal subgroups, and uniqueness can be said only about *maximal* such composition series (having no more refinements).

The hint for (iii)$\Rightarrow$(iv) seems useless in your way, indeed, probably they thought about a proof like (i)$\Rightarrow$(iv)$\Rightarrow$(iii)$\Rightarrow$(ii).